# How Do I Persist Guava AtomicLongMap ?

Tags: java, guava

I have this requirement in which I need my application to generate persistent sequences. Normally, I would use the database but unfortunately, my database doesn't support any sequences.

In this case, I'd like to develop an API in order to persist and I found this class from Google's Guava Library - AtomicLongMap which is what I exactly need. Problem is, I need my values to persist over restarts, Is there anything that I could in order to make it persistent and survive crashes ?

Thanks In Advance, 
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the java application will not be running after a restart, you'll need something outside of the JVM to store the data.

Typically this can be a DB but it sounds like that option doesn't work for you.

Another option is to write the data to a file. When the application starts up it will read the file and populate the AtomicLongMap.

Here's an example of how to read and write state from/to a file:

### Imports

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
```

### Read from file

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AtomicLongMap<String> readFromFile(File file) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException { 

    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);) {


    Map<String,Long>readObj = (Map<String, Long>)ois.readObject();

    return AtomicLongMap.create(readObj);

    }


  }
```

### Write to File

```
public void writeToFile(AtomicLongMap<String>map, File file) throws IOException {
    HashMap<String, Long>newMap = new HashMap<>( map.asMap());

    try(FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);) {

      oos.writeObject(newMap);

    }

  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this answer, what's the best way to write to a file ? Any idea ? Thanks. Is the Preferences API a good way to do this ?

Comment: I don't think the preferences will be the best way.  You may want to call the asMap method and pass that into a new HashMap, which is serializable. Then you can serialize/deserialize the key/value pairs of the map.